# Have Raspberry Pi nginx webpage save checkbox state?

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, nginx, raspberry-pi2

I have a Raspberry Pi running an nginx webpage that uses PHP to change the state of the GPIO pins and turn relays on and off.

Currently I have a checkbox that switches the pin on and off no problem, the problem is that if the page is refreshed or opened in another browser or device the checkbox will revert back to the off position. This doesn't effect the GPIO.

I want to have the state of the checkbox saved on the server end so that when the page is loaded it shows weather the GPIO is on or off, I don't want to use cookies or local storage because that only effects a single browser on a single device.

I have been looking around for a solution but can't seem to find one that fits my issue, any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: So read the state of the GPIO and place that value into your HTML using PHP

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do that, I thought of this method in the beginning which is why I am asking this question.

Comment: If the manual/documentation shows you how the set the pin, I would bet it also shows you how to read the current state of the pin!

Comment: I apologize for asking a stupid question, in all the searching for an answer it never occurred to me that reading the documentation that I had already glanced at might have the answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry Pi PHP GPIO read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103386/raspberry-pi-php-gpio-read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically, you may try to use this *php* command to read the pin state (0 or 1) and according set your checkbox:

```
shell_exec('gpio read [pin number]');
```

Maybe it will be necessary to export the pin to userspace, in console:

```
echo "[pin number]" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio[pin number]/direction
```

Now you can try to read the pin state from your app with:

```
echo shell_exec('cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio[pin number]/value');
```